# Could natural/theta join replace intersection in Relational Algebra?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database, relational-algebra

I have the relation `A1 = (id1, id2)` and the relation `A2 = (id, id1, id2)`, where id, id1, id2 are attributes.

I want to find ***intersection - (A1.id1 = A2.id1 ^ A1.id2 = A2.id2)*** of `A1` and `A2` , but it is impossible in relation algebra because they have different schema.

I want to intersect them **not losing the "id"** data.
(I can not simple project A2 over id1 and id2 and then intersect)

So could I apply ***theta join*** or ***natural join***  here to reach intersection?

Does it return me empty relation if matching does not exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it should return the empty relation if no matching tuples appear in the joined relations.

And yes, intersection is a special case of natural join ergo natural join is a generalization of intersection and ergo natural join can "replace" intersection wherever intersection can be used.  (But you should mind that your particular use case is *NOT* one where "intersection can be used" - and the reason is precisely what you mentioned : the schema's aren't identical.  Don't put the horse behind the cart.)

Answer (score 0):

You can project `A2` over `id1` and `id2` and then intersect the result with `a1`, or you can also apply a natural join and then project the result again over `id1` and `id2`.

This two different approaches produce the same result.

Comment: if I project over id1 and id2 I will lose id

Comment: But if you need an intersection then the two table must have the same number of attributes with the same type.  Otherwise it is not the intersection, the algebraic operator.